# React websocket communication using a custom hook and data stream from backend

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I'm trying to implement a list of components that represents a list of IoT devices that should receive data and update their status.

Each item in the list there's a render a component where there's a button to connect to the socket and update its state.

The problem is that when the data comes from the socket, with a setInterval and and an Observable stream (I can't show the code is under NDA).
Every time I have a new message with an object like this:

```js
{id:1, name:"the name", connected: false, .... }
{id:2, name:"the name 2", connected: false ... and so on }
```

I need the initial list as an array to build the  component, then from a child component I call the `connectByIDà
My attempt was to merge the object in one array, like this and create the first initial structure of the list as an
array, and it works.

```js
[
 {id:1, name:"name", connected:false .... }, 
 {id:2, name:"name 2", connected:false, value: 100 }
]
```

```js
// App.js

// get the data from the socket 
const { items } = useWebsocket("ws://...")

// pass the items to the list
<List items={items} />

// then render the items
items.map(() => <Item item={item} /> 

// in the Item component I use the same hook to get the functions
const { connectById } = useWebsocket()
Item > return .... <button click={connectById(id)} >



// useWebsocket.js
// I have implemented and hook to connect to the websocket
   const [items, setItems]= useState([]) 

   useEffect(() => {
     const socket = new WebSocket(url);

     const connectById = (id) => {
       // the id is the id of the device when I send this message the server starts sending the new data just for this device
       socket.send( {command: "connect", id }) 
     }

     socket.onopen = () => {
       ....
     };

     socket.onclose = () => {
      ...
     };

     socket.onmessage = (event) => {
       // THE PROBLEM IS HERE 
       // I can setup the initial array

       const parsed = JSON.parse(event.data);
       const old = [...items];
       const newData = [...old, parsed];
       setItems((prev) => [...prev, ...newData]);  


       /*
       * When I receive the new data triggered by connectById 
       * function, it looks like the code below every message 
       * and setInterval is just the same device with a new value
       * of course this replace my initial array.
       *
       *  {id:2, name:"name 2", connected:true, value: 100 } 
       *  {id:2, name:"name 2", connected:true, value: 503 }
       *  {id:2, name:"name 2", connected:true, value: 503 }
       */

       return () => {
        socket.close();
       };
   }, [url]);

 return {
    ...
    connectById,
  };
```

I haven't so much experience working with WebSocket.